# Fill between smooth vertical lines

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

I want to fill the area between two curves that are more or less vertical. They go slightly to the side and they are smooth, but the problem is also present when I remove `smooth` from the `\addplot` options. The area between is not shaded as I had expected. Instead I see:

[image]

If I change the coordinates so the lines do not taper to the sides, I get what I expect:

[image]

Is there a way to get the entire area in-between the curves filled in?

This is what I tried:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  xmin=0, xmax=1,
  ymin=0, ymax=1,
]
\addplot [name path=left,gray,thick,mark=none,smooth] coordinates {
    (0.45, 0.25) (0.40, 0.8) (0.35, 1.0) };
\addplot [name path=right,gray,thick,mark=none,smooth] coordinates {
    (0.55, 0.26) (0.60, 0.8) (0.65, 1.0) };
\addplot [gray!90] fill between[of=left and right];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just add `reverse=true` to the `fill between` options.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xmin=0, xmax=1,
      ymin=0, ymax=1,
    ]
        \addplot [name path=left,blue,thick,mark=none,smooth] coordinates {
            (0.45, 0.25) (0.40, 0.8) (0.35, 1.0) };
        \addplot [name path=right,red,thick,mark=none,smooth] coordinates {
            (0.55, 0.26) (0.60, 0.8) (0.65, 1.0) };
        \addplot [gray!90] fill between[
            of=left and right,
            reverse=true,
        ];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]